# error verify data in database on login python (tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem verifying a login. For example, I have 3 records in the database and only 1 user and password are valid, the other two are 2, it always throws me to the "ELIF" that the data is incorrect.

what can be due to that?

I have
user: 1
password: 1

user: 2
password: 2

user: 3
password: 3

Well, of these 3 users, only user 3 fits me well, the other 2 users send me to the "elif" of incorrect data, when everything is fine.

```
self.connection2 = connect_to_database()
   self.cursor2 = self.connection2.cursor()
   # Ejemplo: Ejecutar una consulta para obtener datos
   self.cursor2.execute("SELECT nombre,password FROM usuarios")
   self.data2 = self.cursor2.fetchall()
   #messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia", self.data2)
   # Cerrar el cursor y la conexión

   for self.fila in self.data2:
       self.v_email = self.fila[0]
       self.v_password = self.fila[1]

   self.cursor2.close()
   self.connection2.close()

   if self.entry_email.get() == "" or self.entry_password.get() == "":
       self.dialogo = tk.Toplevel()
       self.dialogo.title("ERROR")
       self.dialogo.geometry("300x50")
       self.dialogo.resizable(0,0)

       self.wtotal2 = self.dialogo.winfo_screenwidth()
       self.htotal2 = self.dialogo.winfo_screenheight()

       self.wventana2 = 300
       self.hventana2 = 100

       self.pwidth2 = round(self.wtotal2/2-self.wventana2/2)
       self.pheight2 = round(self.htotal2/2-self.hventana2/2)

       self.dialogo.geometry(str(self.wventana2)+"x"+str(self.hventana2)+"+"+str(self.pwidth2)+"+"+str(self.pheight2))
       self.etiqueta = tk.Label(self.dialogo, text="Rellena todos los campos.", padx=10, pady=10)
       self.etiqueta.pack()

       self.image_boton_vale = Image.open("src/boton_vale.png")
       self.photo_boton_vale = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image_boton_vale)

       self.boton_vale = tk.Button(self.dialogo, image=self.photo_boton_vale, command=self.cerrar_dialogo_vale)
       self.boton_vale.pack(pady=5)
       self.boton_vale.place(x=86, y=50, width=128, height=31)

   elif self.entry_email.get() == self.v_email and self.entry_password.get() == self.v_password:
       self.app.root.destroy()
       self.ventana_menu = Menus(self)
   else:
       self.app.root.destroy()
       messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia", "Los datos introducidos son incorrectos.")
```

What could cause this error?